# Is it possible to use media_sideload_image to upload local files?

Tags: uploads, media

I want to add `media_sideload_image` to upload a file programmatically . I've got it working when the image URL is online (e.g. http://etc...) but not when it's a local file from my hardrive or network drive (e.g. file://etc). I get the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string`.

Is this possible? I'm guessing there must be some way around it as the Wordpress admin site can upload local files.

Comment: files uploaded via the admin are done using a `<form>` and the `$_FILES` variable

Comment: Image can not be uploaded with folder path, they can be uploaded if you can move them on a url like http://localhost/images

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using the media_handle_upload() function. This is a working example that you can use as a guide for your requirements:

*First Create your HTML form*

```
<form method="post" id="uploadCartaAnno" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <input class="text-input" name="carta_ano" type="file" id="carta_ano" multiple="false"/>
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
                        <input name="updatecarta_ano" type="submit" id="updatecarta_ano" class="hp-btn-file -icon-upload" value="Subir formato" />
                        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
                    </form>
```

Then your PHP code

```
if (
                        isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'] )
                        && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
                      ) {
                        // The nonce is valid and it is safe to continue.

                        // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
                        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

                        // Let WordPress handle the upload.
                        
                        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'carta_ano', $comId );

                        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                          // There was an error uploading the image.
                        } else {
                          // The image was uploaded successfully!
                        }

                      } else {

                        // Show some error message if nonce fails.
                      }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to actually answer the question